# I have to change db everytime when project updated What Should I do?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, web-hosting

My DB is Postgres and Code in Django,
I live a project daily but I want old DB in a new project which has only just some updates in it but If I don't Update it It shows migration error and if I use --fake then on that page it will show similar error 'Programming Error Column Does Not Exist' I tried each and every way pls help me.
Thanks

Comment: After you update the code on the production server, you still need to run the `python runserver migrate` command to update the database on the production server.

Comment: That Causes Db Errors

Comment: Did you run `python runserver makemigrations` first?

Comment: yes, of course I ran it and It showed No Changes Detected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying for many days I notice that there are errors in fields not matching so I just replace or update my old project models.py to my new project models.py and make migrations and migrate again and then I go to my new project and I run migrate and it runs correctly.